# How to insert a file into sql-server via tiny_tds?

Tags: sql-server, ruby, sql-server-2000, tiny-tds

In a data importing script:

```
 client = TinyTds.Client.new(...)
 insert_str = "INSERT INTO [...] (...) VALUE (...)"
 client.execute(insert_str).do
```

So far so good.

However, how can I attach a `.pdf` file into the `varbinary` field (SQL Server 2000)?

Comment: `OPENROWSET`? : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276850%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Comment: Not only is saving binary data to SQLServer a nightmare, but so is the query to read it.  I have done this in PHP and ColdFusion, if you'd like to see a snippet in one of those languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using activerecord:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'tiny_tds'
require 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'

..

my_table.create(:file_name => "abc.pdf", :file_data => File.open("abc.pdf", "rb").read)
```

For SQLServer 2000 support, go for 2.3.x version `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter` gem.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently had the same issue and using activerecord was not really adapted for what I wanted to do...

So, without using activerecord:

```
client = TinyTds.Client.new(...)
data = "0x" + File.open(file, 'rb').read.unpack('H*').first
insert_str = "INSERT INTO [...] (...) VALUE (... #{data})"
client.execute(insert_str).do
```

To send proper varbinary data, you need to read the file, convert it to hexadecimal string with `unpack('H*').first` and prepend '0x' to the result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is PHP-MSSQL code to save binary data:

```
mssql_query("SET TEXTSIZE 2147483647",$link);
$sql = "UPDATE UploadTable SET UploadTable_Data = ".varbinary_encode($data)." WHERE Person_ID = '".intval($p_id)."'";
mssql_query($sql,$link)  or 
  die('cannot upload_resume() in '.__FILE__.' on line '.__LINE__.'.<br/>'.mssql_get_last_message());

function varbinary_encode($data=null) {
  $encoded = null;
  if (!is_null($data)) {
    $a = unpack("H*hex", $data);
    $encoded = "0x";
    $encoded .= $a['hex'];
  }
  return $encoded;
}
```

Here is PHP-MSSQL code to get binary data:

```
mssql_query("SET TEXTSIZE 2147483647",$link);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM UploadTable WHERE ID = 123";
$db_result = mssql_query($sql,$link);
// work with result like normal
```

Comment: I also have Cold Fusion code and PHP-SQLSRV based code snippets if you need them.

Comment: Which version of SQLServer? 2000?